# Help with jot form pro embed code

Tags: embed

I've been trying to add this code to my blog:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://form.jotformpro.com/jsform/50926150380955"></script>
```

But Wordpress won't save the change.

Any suggestions will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/jotform-oembed/

After you have successfully installed it, all you need to do is paste in the JotForm URL on the post or page where you want it to appear:

[image: Pasted jotForm URL]

You can get your JotForm URL from the JotForm builder as shown below:

[image]

Going by your Script Embed code you shared, your JotForm URL should be :

```
http://form.jotformpro.com/form/50926150380955
```

~~

Here's how it looks when embedded: http://tituswptest.qsandbox.com/?page_id=24

Use code '0000' to access the test page above.

Hope that helps.

~~

Here's the plugin code, just in case the link goes down or the plugin is removed:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: JotForm oEmbed
    Plugin URI: http://www.jotform.com/labs/wordpress
    Description:
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Ertugrul Emre Ertekin
    Author URI: http://ee.ertek.in
    License: GNU General Public License v3
*/

class JotFormOEmbed {

    public function __construct() {
        wp_oembed_add_provider( '#https?://(secure\.|www\.|form\.)?(my)?jotform(pro|eu|z)?\.(com|net|us|ca|me|co)/form/[0-9]*#i', 'https://www.jotform.com/oembed/', true );
    }

}

$jotformOEmbed = new JotFormOEmbed();

?>
```